# set creation using constructor

Tags: constructor, set

This is actually in my Python course manual, yet VS-Code flags it with syntax errors at the quoted elements.  I just don't get this.
my_set =  set(['X', 1, 'yesterday', 56.9])
or
my_set =  set(["X", 1, "yesterday", 56.9])

Sets are an unordered mutable data structure that contains no duplicates.
Why is this violating Microsoft's gospel?

What's more, why are companies teaching this if its inaccurate? (I don't really expect an answer to that of course, but perhaps this is a deprecated form?)

Comment: Sounds like you've got an error somewhere you haven't shown us, likely on a previous line.